# AngularJS - TypeError: $window.print is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some troubles whith print function in AngularJS. I have a button wich call au print function in my controller. But I have just that error :

```
TypeError: $window.print is not a function
```

HTML :

```
<md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="printThis()">Imprimer</md-button>
```

JS :

```
$scope.printThis = function(){
    console.info("Let go print !");
    alert("PLOP");
    window.alert("FOO");
    $window.alert("BAR");
    $window.print();
};
```

When I click on button, I have 3 alerts then the TypeError ! I tried both window.print() and $window.print() but nothing works... I really don't understand ! If i press ctrl + P, the chrome popup to print appears normally...

Need help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your controller needs to inject the `$window` dependency,

```
.controller("YourController", function($window, $scope) {
   $scope.printThis = function(){
      $window.alert("BAR");
  };
}
```

If that doesn't work, I suggest you to remove any html element with an id of "alert" or "print".

If you have html element with id "print", it will overwrite window.print variable.

Comment: Sounds like he is already doing that... otherwise he would get the error on the line with $window.alert(...).

Comment: Like it ! I will search for "print" id or element or attribute in HTML ;-)

Comment: The problem comes from my module declaration. I set `var print = angular.module('PrintModule', ['PrintServices']);`, I rename in `var printModule = ...` and problem solved :-)

Comment: you can use function scopes so you won't do this in the future:  (function(){ ...your code here...})(); that won't expose any variables to global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Angular limits the access to the `window` object (or any other global variable).

To access `$window` you have to first inject it into the `controller`

```
angular.module('App', []).controller('Cnt', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.print = function() {
    $window.print();
  }
});
```

Small demonstration: http://plnkr.co/edit/E0oCSuE3xceHp1Jtjh7g?p=preview

Comment: Sounds like he is already doing that... otherwise he would get the error on the line with $window.alert(...).

Comment: Absolutely, I inject `$window` in my `controller`. I think I have a conflict problem, when I do a `console.debug($window)`, I see all properties but not print function ! Research in progress...